# empty json file after crawling using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a simple code for web crawler using scrapy. The code for my test can be found below.

```py
import scrapy

class ExtractUrls(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "extract"

    # request function
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [ 'https://www.iitdh.ac.in/events.php', ]

        for url in urls: 
            yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse)

    # Parse function
    def parse(self, response):

        # Extra feature to get title 
        title = response.css('title::text').extract_first()  

        # Get anchor tags 
        links = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()

        for link in links:
            yield
            {
                'title': title,
                'links': link
            }
```

#### items.py

```py
import scrapy

class GfgItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    name = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

#### settings.py

```py
BOT_NAME = 'gfg'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['gfg.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'gfg.spiders'

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'gfg (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

When I run `$scrapy crawl extract -o links.json -t json`, I want the output to be stored in `links.json` file, but my `links.json` file remains empty. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `GfgItem()`:

```
from items import GfgItem
.....
    for link in links: 
        item = GfgItem()
        item["title"] = title
        item["name"] = link
        yield item
```